# Perl script works with Apache piped logs but not Python script

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, python, perl

I need to port my Perl log handling script to Python. Here is a simple example of a Perl script I can use:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

$|=1; # Use unbuffered output

while(<>) {
   system("beep");
}
```

As you can probably see, I am telling the system to beep whenever a request is made to test the script. Everything works fine on this one, but when I try a Python script such as this:

```
import sys
import os

for line in sys.stdin:
    os.system('beep')
```

everything runs but the system does not beep after a request. Here are the lines I was and am using in my apache configuration file:

```
CustomLog "|perl /var/web/onhit.pl" "onhit"   <-OLD LINE
CustomLog "|python /var/web/onhit.py" "onhit" <-NEW LINE
```

I am following [this email](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-January/695185.html) on the Python mailing list. Anyone have an idea why this is not working?

EDIT: I know the problem has something to do with "for line in sys.stdin". For some reason it is just not detecting anything in stdin. I have no idea whether it is my python script or my apache configuration causing this, though.

Comment: If your problem is related to the actual script you might find you get better answers on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting **beep** from?  Have you tried putting in the full path to this **beep** command?

Edited to add code sample.

Last time I hacked something in python to read stdin as a pipe my code looked like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

while 1:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  else:
    print >> sys.stdout,  'got: %s' % line.strip()
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Beep is a command on my machine that makes the system beep. It is in the path variable so I do not need to list the full path. I know it is not that line giving me the trouble; that is just a test to see if things are working.

Comment: This sounds like the most likely reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i guess the guy on the mailing list didn't know what he was talking about. It makes sense that the stdin test should be in a while, and not a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Low hanging fruit:  paths, permissions, ownerships.

Comment: Well it doesn't really matter, but onhit.py has execute permissions, and I know all the paths are right. Ownerships are both root.